# Assigning event to subscribe with new

Tags: c#, events, delegates, event-handling

I'm making QuestSystem in unity.

what i want to do is assigning to my questData an event so it can know when the quest objective has been completed.

Lets say there is a class named `A` and action called `a`.

and i want Class `B`, Action `b` want to have reference to `A.a`

So if i do

`b = A.a;`,

`b+= someAction;`, it actually does `a+=someAction;`

but when if i do that. It will just simply `b+=someAction` and `A.a` will remain `null`

what should i do to perform what i want?

here are some tags. (i don't know what the answer would be. so..)

```
# event
# subscribing event
# assigning event
# referencing event
# action
# delegate
```

*====== Edited =======*
here is my code.

QuestData.cs

```
public class QuestData
{
    public string questName;
    public string qusetID;
    public string questDescription;
    public SceneType questSceneType;

    private string isActivePrefsKey { get { return $"QuestKey{qusetID}"; } }
    public bool isActive {
        get {
            return Convert.ToBoolean (PlayerPrefs.GetInt (isActivePrefsKey));
        }
        set { PlayerPrefs.SetInt (isActivePrefsKey, Convert.ToInt16 (value)); }
    }
    public QuestObjective questObjective;
    public QuestReward questReward;


    public void Activate ()
    {
        if (AppController.CurrentScene == questSceneType) {
            questObjective.ActivateObjective ();

        }
    }

}
```

QuestObjective.cs

```
public class QuestObjective
{
    // TODO rename all
    public int goalObjectiveCount;
    public int currentObjectiveCount;


    public Action questAction;

    public void OnConditionMatch ()
    {
        Debug.Log ("OnConditionMatch");
        currentObjectiveCount += 1;
    }

    public void ActivateObjective ()
    {
        questAction += OnConditionMatch;
    }


}
```

QuestManager.cs

```
public class QuestManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    List<QuestData> questDatas;


    void Awake ()
    {
        PrepareQuestDatas ();
        ActivateActiveQuests ();
    }


    void ActivateActiveQuests ()
    {
        var activeQuests = GetActiveQuests ();
        foreach (var activeQuest in activeQuests) {
            activeQuest.Activate ();
        }
    }


    List<QuestData> GetActiveQuests ()
    {
        // for debuging
        return questDatas;

        // real code
        return questDatas.Where (q => q.isActive == true).ToList ();
    }



    public void PrepareQuestDatas ()
    {
        questDatas = new List<QuestData> {
            new QuestData {
                questName = "Foot Print",
                questDescription  = "win the game for first time",
                questSceneType = SceneType.Main,
                questObjective = new QuestObjective {
                    goalObjectiveCount = 1,
                    questAction = GamePlayController.instance.endGameCon.onWinGame
                },
                questReward = new QuestCoinReward{
                    rewardAmount = 100,
                },
            }
        };
    }


}
```

Comment: The answer to the question you're asking is to give `B` a reference to the `A` in question: `B.MyReferenceToSomeA.a += someAction;` But I'm not sure this isn't [an XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: *i don't know what i want. so..* - maybe you should try to be more precise about your problem

Comment: @adjan edited.  i sure do know what i want haha

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post [a minimal example of what needs to change](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and fully explain what needs to be modified. You may also want to read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

One potential solution is to create a new set of EventArgs, like this:

```
public class QuestCompletedEventArgs : System.EventArgs
{
    public QuestObjective FinishedObjective { get; }
    public QuestCompletedEventArgs(QuestObjective objectiveIn) {
        this.FinishedObjective = objectiveIn;
    }
}
```

(probably in a different file)
... and use it like this:

First, create an event delegate:

```
public delegate void QuestObjectiveCompleteHandler(object sender, QuestCompletedEventArgs e);
```

Instantiate the event delegate:

```
public event QuestObjectiveCompletedHandler CompletedObjective;
```

Define the method that will do something when the objective is completed:

```
public void ObjectiveCompleted(object sender, QuestCompletedEventArgs e) 
{
    // do something 
}
```

Assign that method to the event:

```
this.CompletedObjective += this.ObjectiveCompleted;
```

From here, you can make the `FinishedObjective` object within the `QuestCompletedEventArgs` a `List<QuestObjective>`, and `FinishedObjective.add(objectiveIn)` whenever appropriate.

You should also be able to make the event handling method act differently when a certain amount of objectives have been completed, or whatever you want to do with that information.

Of course, you can also add multiple different methods to respond to this event by adding more `this.CompletedObjective += this.methodName;` lines, as long as the signature of the new method(s) carry that same signature.

Answer (score 0):

Reading into your example, I have written up some code where "A" is `QuestObjective` and "B" is `Quest`.  The `Quest` object needs to know when objective has been marked as completed.

Using event handlers, we can set it up so that B is notified when an action occurs on A.

Like this:

```
// B
public class Quest
{
    public Quest()
    {
        Objectives = new List<QuestObjective>();
        // load objectives... Fake
        Objectives.Add(new QuestObjective("obj 1"));
        Objectives.Add(new QuestObjective("obj 2"));
        Objectives.Add(new QuestObjective("obj 3"));

        foreach(var o in Objectives) // subscribe to QuestObjective events
        {
            o.ObjectiveCompleted += (sender, args) => ReportObjectiveCompleted();
        }
    }

    public void ReportObjectiveCompleted()
    {
        // let 'em know
    }

    public List<QuestObjective> Objectives { get; set; }
}

// A
public class QuestObjective
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public QuestObjective(string name = "unknown")
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public event EventHandler ObjectiveCompleted;

    public void MarkCompleted()
    {
        // when a task is marked as complete and IF there are 
        // subscribers to this event then call the event handler
        var a = ObjectiveCompleted;
        if (a != null)
        {
            a(this, new EventArgs()); // use different event args to pass data
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.
(in your code)but what i want is Telling which event tells QuestObjective to be completed..

some lik this.
via new QuestObjective{ eventToSubscribe = GameController.onWinGame }

Comment: Your `QuestObjective` implementation is confusing to me. You're using `Action` incorrectly.  You are setting `questAction` in your `PrepareQuestDatas` method and in the `QuestObjective.ActivateObjective` -- but you never call it, like this: `questAction()` -- when should it be invoked?

Comment: thats the question. the reason i am using action is to subscribe the event wich is assigned to that. 
but i dont know how..

i dont want to call assiged action. i want the action called by assigning acton.

Comment: You need to chain two events together. Your current approach w

Comment: how can i do that?